# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy usando la librería ***auto py to exe*** para pasar un archivo de python a .exe . Peero al convertir ***prueba.py*** me salta un error y me da este Traceback que no sé a que se puede deber.

```
File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1638, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 382, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2055, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2093, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2912, in _load_package
    self._load_module(fqname, fp, buf, stuff)
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2105, in _load_module
    co = compile(contents, pathname, 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST, True)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Es una traza de error más larga pero pongo solo una parte. Pongo la estructura del proyecto en la que solo uso el paquete ***img*** , los demás archivos de python no los uso , solo quiero pasar el ***pruebas.py*** . mainClass y preprocesamiento no los uso para nada.
¿A qué se debe este error?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece ser un problema relacionado con el formato de codificación. Puedes usar *Notepad++* para cambiar el formato de codificación de tus archivos *.py* a UTF-8. Aquí tienes mas información: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes

Comment: Te refieres a importar el archivo en Notepad++ y guardarlo como UTF-8?

Comment: y lo del sed no puedo utilizarlo , estoy en Windows

Comment: Como UTF-8 sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Si, me refería a eso. Si dices que aun así no funciona no se que puede ser la verdad.

Comment: Asegúrate de que todos esos `.py` que tienes sean realmente fuentes python. Parece que hayas cometido algún error y alguno de ellos sea un binario. De otro modo no entiendo cómo un fuente python puede tener caracteres nulos (ni siquiera UTF-8 tiene nada qué ver aquí, pues un carácter nulo tiene la misma codificación en cualquier estándar, ASCII, UTF-8, Windows, etc.. Es un byte que en binario vale 00000000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema parece la existencia de bytes "nulos", es decir, con el valor ascii `0x00` dentro del fichero fuente, si no dispones de un linux puedes usar la propia consola de python para eliminarlos.

He creaddo un fichero prueba.py con un caracter `0x00` para reproducir el error

```
python3 #Ejecutado desde el directorio donde se encuentra pueba.py
>>> with open('prueba.py', 'rb') as f: code = f.read()
...
>>> code
b"print('Hola')\n\x00"
# La siguiente línea es para comprobar que se produce el mismo error, no es estrictamente necesaria para la solución
>>> eval(code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
# La siguiente línea elimina los caracteres nulos
>>> with open('prueba2.py', 'wb') as f: f.write(code.replace(b'\x00', b''))
```

Se crea un fichero `prueba2.py` igual que `prueba.py` pero sin los caracteres nulos, no reemplazo directamente `prueba.py` por seguridad, pero una vez verificado que está OK, habría que sustituirlo.

Por cierto, te recomiendo que uses en Windows el [WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/wsl/install-win10) para disponer de un linux con sus comandos que ayuda en ciertas situaciones, especialmente si estás desarrollando