# Error al importar Path de unipath

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa con Django y siguiendo algunos tutoriales se usa unipath para las rutas y al llamarlo en el archivo de configuración de python me manda el siguiente error

```
from unipath import Path
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Aún no entiendo porque razón si al verificar que este instalado, sí aparece en el entorno

Answer (score 0):

¿Puede ser que tengas caracteres nulos en el fichero que intentas ejecutar?

Intenta corregirlo con el siguiente comando:

```
sed -i 's/\x0//g' ficheroQueIntentasEjecutar
```

Haz un backup por si acaso.

Si no estás en Linux y no tienes forma de ejecutar con un sed, podrías guiarte de la siguiente pregunta en la que sucede un caso similar y podrías corregirlo usando python:

[ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/321219/valueerror-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes)